# checked for multiple checkbox in update form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is my blade file for the update form. So how I should I retrieve those data in the form by checked the checkbox.

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label form-control-label" for="input-description">Hobbies</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" class="form-control-label" value="football" > Football
                    &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" class="form-control-label" value="basketball"> Basketball
                     <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" class="form-control-label" value="table_tennis"> Table Tennis
                     <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" class="form-control-label" value="hockey"> Hockey
                     <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" class="form-control-label" value="others"> Others
                </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

This is my Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $student=Student::find($id);
    return view('students.edit', compact('student'));
}
```

In the database, .hobbies are stored in hobbies column like this

```
["basketball","football",'table_tennis']
```

Comment: you want to check the checkboxes based on the database values on the update page?

Comment: @OMiShah yes Right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use foreach loop inside blade that will be more maintainable:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label form-control-label" for="input-description">Hobbies</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @foreach($hobbies as $hobby)
                <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" @if(in_array($hobby,$checked_hobbies)) checked @endif class="form-control-label" value="{{ $hobby }}" > {{ $hobby }}
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

and of course you should pass `hobbies` and `checked_hobbies` array in controller:

```
$hobbies = ["basketball","football",'table_tennis'];
    $checked_hobbies = ["basketball","football"];
    return view('test', compact('hobbies','checked_hobbies'));
```

Comment: @SauravShrestha I strongly suggest to split create, read, update, delete methods it is good for maintaining and from an app design perspective if you can't split them (create, update) then add check if you already have data for that `student`

Comment: Thanks
but my form is for both create and update so I want to null for create so I have done
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="{{ $hobby }}" {{ in_array('rice', $sale->purpose ?? null) ? 'checked' : '' }}> Rice
and error is in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given How should I solve this ?

Comment: Best solution will be to create separate blades for each method that is not hard and more convenient, as further there can be more differences than null hobbies checked. Again if it is not an option then you should create some kind of flag(variable that will tell the blade that is for create now or update) `$method='update'; ... compact('update'));` then check in you blade `@if($method == 'update') case update @else case create @endif`